# Checking server status on multiple machines from C# application

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, windows-services, filesystems

I have multiple content servers on different machines.  I need to check the status of every server.  I'm concerned about things like disk size, priority etc.

One solution that I'm using now is to install a Window Service on each machine which regularly checks the server but I have to manually install the service on each server.

Is there any way I can get the server information like disk space from a WCF service or using a windows application?  I want to create a single watcher for my servers as I have to add servers sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at windows WMI you can make remote calls to machines so long as you have permissions to do so. You will only have to run one service on one server that can connect to the others.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have Read WMI and Found somewhere that you need to map Network Drives but i dont need this thing my Servers are separate from each other and i need a Appliaction which tells me about the Disk Space available on each server